# Staking results query Join

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In Access I have one table containing some loans and two other tables containing derivatives (the columns’ names are almost the same)

Here are the table:

Table 1

```
LoanNumber    MappingID  
Loan1         M1         
Loan2         M2
```

Table 2

```
DerivativeANumber    MappingID    StartDate
DerA1                M1           1-1-2010
DerA2                M1           1-1-2012
```

Table 3

```
DerivativeBNumber  MappingID    StartDate
DerB1              M1           1-1-2005
DerB2              M2           1-1-2012
```

I would like to retrieve the lowest StartDate among the two type of derivatives associated with each loan (by the MappingID).

For example, for Loan1 I would get:

```
LoanNumber  DerivativeNumber    StartDate
Loan1       DerB1               1-1-2005
```

I have tried LEFT JOINs but can’t figure out a way of “stacking” the results of the joins together.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show attempted query and try using a union query.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something along the lines of

```
SELECT
    A.LoanNumber
    , MIN(StartDate) as Min_StartDate
FROM
    TABLE1 as A
    LEFT JOIN       
    (SELECT DerivativeANumber as DerivativeNumber, MappingID, StartDate FROM TABLE2)        
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT DerivativeBNumber as DerivativeNumber, MappingID, StartDate FROM TABLE3) as B
    ON (A.MappingID = B.MappingID)
GROUP BY
    A.LoanNumber
```

should should prove a starting point

- first, merge your `Table2` and `Table3` into one table.

  There's several ways to do this, I used `UNION ALL`, another alternative would be to `INSERT` the data into a new, tempoary table
- since I used `UNION ALL`, I had to rename the headers first with `(SELECT DerivativeANumber as DerivativeNumber, MappingID, StartDate FROM TABLE2)` (x2)
- then we query the result of your `UNION ALL`, calculate the `Min(StartDate)` for each combination of `LoanNumber` by grouping by those fields.
- then, you add your `DerivativeNumber` by `Left Join`to you merged table.

Hope that helps

Comment: Pretty sure the group by  on derivativeNumber negates the min as you will still get 2 derivative's each with the original date.  I think you're on the right path with the union but you need to get JUST the  min date  for a mapping ID and then join back to your union to get the derivativeNumber for that date. (assuming there's only 1 with that date, so maybe a top 1 is needed as well.

Comment: @xQbert you're totally right, I misread that. If `LoanNumber` to `MappingID` is `1:1`, then groupint by `LoanNumber` and retrieving the associated `DerivativeNumber` by Left Joining the result to `Table2 UNION Table3` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using a DISTINCT Top 1 instead of the Min() did the trick! Thanks a lot guys!

Solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1
    A.LoanNumber
    , B.DerivativeNumber
    , StartDate as Min_StartDate
FROM
    TABLE1 as A
    LEFT JOIN       
    (SELECT DerivativeANumber as DerivativeNumber, MappingID, StartDate FROM TABLE2)        
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT DerivativeBNumber as DerivativeNumber, MappingID, StartDate FROM TABLE3) as B
    ON (A.MappingID = B.MappingID)    
WHERE A.LoanNumber = Loan1
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Comment: Will fail if you need to look for multiple loans at one time. as top 1 will only return 1 (the one with the earliest startdate. based on your `order by startdate (asc)`